# Powershell: PSScheduledJob for non-admin

Tags: powershell, winrm, scheduler, remoting, task

Is there a way for non-admins to use the PSScheduledJob module? For example, I tried Register-ScheduledJob without admin privilege, but it returns "Access is Denied" error. We know that we can allow non-admin to use PSRemoting (such as New-PSSession), by changing the PSSessionConfiguration:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/23/you-don-t-have-to-be-an-administrator-to-run-remote-powershell-commands.aspx

Is there a way to do the same for Scheduling Jobs? I would like to allow non-admins to Schedule Jobs and stuffs

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this handy tip from Ben Shy an MS Employee on his TechNet blog.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/benshy/archive/2012/06/04/using-a-powershell-script-to-run-as-a-different-user-amp-elevate-the-process.aspx

You could add the whole of the PSScheduled job command embedded in that session.

How you get the creds in there without the user knowing is a different matter.

Two things, you may need unrestricted excecution policy (I haven't tested yet) AND you may need to store your creds somewhere (potentially insecure)

I don't know your network or requirements so cant advise on that  :-0

Yours

Ed

dont forget to vote useful and mark answered if it is!